# How to sudo to admin user after SFTP connection

Tags: linux, sudo, sftp, su

I have a requirement to `sudo` to user 'admin' after connecting to SFTP server with below command.

```
sftp user@hostname
sftp> sudo su - admin
Invalid command.
```

Is there any other way I can use `sudo`?

Comment: The answers are correct but one minor piece of advice. `sudo su - admin` is unnecessary. You can simplify the command to `sudo -u admin`, either with or without additional `-i `.

Answer (score 5):

It's not completely true that you cannot change the user with SFTP.

For example, even if you are connecting to the common OpenSSH server, you can instruct it to run the SFTP subsystem/server with elevated privileges using a SFTP server startup command like:

```
sudo /path/to/sftp-server
```

For example with OpenSSH `sftp` client you can use something like:

```
sftp -s "sudo /path/to/sftp-server" user@example.com
```

Or with (my) WinSCP SFTP client you can also override the SFTP server start command (both in [GUI](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_sftp) and scripting).

But there's lot of limitations to allow this working. Particularly the `sudo` may not require password and TTY. For details, see WinSCP FAQ [How do I change user after login (e.g. su root)?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su)

Comment: oh good trick! Yeah, true. This *is* a possible workaround in case you can do noninteractive sudo auth. Nice!

Answer (score 4):

FTP / SFTP is not a shell in which you can run commands. It's a very specific-purpose protocol for the transfer of files and related operations. The `sftp` program hence can only give you a command interface to the features of that protocol.

So, by the very design of what `sftp` is not, you can't.

**If** you have shell access to the same server through plain `ssh`, then you can run commands like `sudo` and access the files you care about from there, and, for example, put them in an archive file, give that access rights for exclusively the user you originally logged in, and then copy that.